# IsReference property in data contract

Tags: wcf, datacontract

What is the purpose of `IsReference` property in `DataContract`? How does the request and response vary with this property applied?

Answer (score 67):

It determines how objects are serialized, by default, `IsReference=false`.

Setting `IsReference = true` allows the serialization of trees of objects that can reference each other. So with a list of `Employees` that each have a property for `Manager` (who is also an `Employee`), a reference to the `Manager` for each `Employee` can be held rather than embedding the `Manager` within each `Employee` node:

`IsReference=false` would produce:

```
<Employee> 
      <Manager i:nil=“true“ /> 
      <Name>Kenny</Name> 
</Employee> 
<Employee> 
      <Manager> 
            <Manager i:nil=“true“ /> 
            <Name>Kenny</Name> 
      </Manager>  
      <Name>Bob</Name> 
</Employee> 
<Employee> 
      <Manager> 
            <Manager i:nil=“true“ /> 
            <Name>Kenny</Name> 
      </Manager>  
      <Name>Alice</Name> 
</Employee>
```

Where as `IsReference=true` would produce:

```
<Employee z:Id=“i1“ xmlns:z=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/“> 
      <Manager i:nil=“true“ />  
      <Name>Kenny</Name> 
</Employee> 
<Employee z:Id=“i2“ xmlns:z=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/“> 
      <Manager z:Ref=“i1“ />  
      <Name>Bob</Name> 
</Employee> 
<Employee z:Id=“i3“ xmlns:z=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/“> 
      <Manager z:Ref=“i1“ />  
      <Name>Alice</Name> 
</Employee>
```

Snippets taken from this [weblog](http://zamd.net/wcf/2008/05/20/datacontract-serializer-and-isreference-property.html) that has a full explanation along with examples of the generated XML with the property applied.

MSDN - [IsReference Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx) provides details as well as [Interoperable Object References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656708.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Also `IsReference` does not exist in .NET Framework 3.5. So you could get errors when using it with that Framework version - it only exists in 4.5, 4, 3.5 SP1 and Silverlight.

> "Error 297 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'IsReference' "