# Error deserializing XML with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am deserializing xml to objects with this method:

```
public T Deserialize(string filename)
{
    var xml = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(xml);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj = (T)dcs.ReadObject(stream);
    return obj;
}
```

I have an old XML, and since then some properties added/removed from the a class I am serializing/deserializing.

I have the following exception:

> Deserialized object with reference id 'i53' not found in stream.

Is it possible to customize the DataContractSerializer to just skip a property if it is not in the model anymore?  Note that the deleted property is a reference to another complex object, not to simple type. The XML file contains that, my class not anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I ignore a property when serializing using the DataContractSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer)

Comment: @WimOmbelets Please read both questions. They are two different topic...

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] of your problem.  It sounds like something is going wrong with [object reference tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037201/isreference-property-in-data-contract).  For instance, possibly you obsoleted a data member where an object is defined, so a later reference to the object in the XML via a `"z:Ref"` attribute fails.

Comment: @dbc Your are right, I did not mention in the question, that the deleted property is a reference to another complex object, not to simple type. The XML file contains that, my class not anymore.

Comment: Making a property private in a class will exclude property from xml.  But you are getting an error when deserializing.  You error is occurring because the xml contains a property that is not in the class.  So if some of your xml files contain a tag then it must be in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message `Deserialized object with reference id 'i53' not found in stream` can get thrown when you enable the data contract serializer's [object reference preservation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmy/2006/03/26/preserving-object-reference-in-wcf/) functionality.  It indicates that, during deserialization, a reference to an undefined object was encountered, and so cannot be deserialized.

I was able to reproduce the problem by obsoleting a data member as follows.  First, I defined the following types:

```
namespace V1
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Member", Namespace = "Question45008433", IsReference = true)]
    public class Member
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Root", Namespace = "Question45008433")]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public Member MainMember { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I created a test object as follows:

```
var list = new List<V1.Member> { new V1.Member { Name = "Foo" }, new V1.Member { Name = "Bar" } };
var v1 = new V1.RootObject { MainMember = list[0], Members = list };
```

Notice that the `Foo` object is referred to twice, once from `MainMember` and once from the `Members` list.

When I serialized this using `DataContractSerializer`, I got the following XML:

```
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Question45008433">
  <MainMember z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <Name>Foo</Name>
  </MainMember>
  <Members>
    <Member z:Ref="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <Member z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <Name>Bar</Name>
    </Member>
  </Members>
</Root>
```

Notice that the `Foo` object is fully serialized when it is *first serialized* as `<MainMember>`, whereupon it is given a `z:Id="i1"` attribute.  When subsequent references are encountered during serialization, only a reference is serialized via `z:Ref="i1"`.

Next, I decided that the `MainMember` data member was unnecessary and obsoleted it:

```
namespace V2
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Member", Namespace = "Question45008433", IsReference = true)]
    public class Member
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Root", Namespace = "Question45008433")]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to deserialize the original XML using this modified contract, I get the very exception you are seeing:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Deserialized object with reference id 'i1' not found in stream.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.GetExistingObject(String id, Type type, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.TryHandleNullOrRef(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns, Object& retObj)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract)
```

Why is this happening?  It occurs because the obsoleted data member came **before** the remaining data members.  Thus, during deserialization, the defining element is **skipped and ignored**, and the subsequent references cannot get resolved.

The workaround is to add back the original data member as a private fake synthetic property that does nothing and always returns `null`:

```
namespace V3
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Member", Namespace = "Question45008433", IsReference = true)]
    public class Member
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Root", Namespace = "Question45008433")]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
        Member MainMember
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }


        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The original XML can now be deserialized successfully because, during deserialization, the data contract serializer itself maintains a lookup table of all reference elements by name.  However, the `z:Ref="i1"` element only gets added when encountered if it corresponds to a currently valid member.  And, because `EmitDefaultValue = false`, the obsoleted element will no longer appear when serialized.

Comment: Thank you for this great effort, you perfectly reproduced and solved my problem that I did not even describe properly.

Comment: Is nt that we can skip if there is an extra element found while deserialization?

I mean , we should be always able to deserialize to what we want even if there are extra members present in the serialized content right ?